# Autocomplete not working on IE11 and Safari browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, autocomplete, internet-explorer-11

Good evening everyone. I'm implementing the autocomplete function as source code below. But when I apply it to IE11, it doesn't work, it doesn't do autocomplete when the user enters, but only works when we click on the input. I went to find the cause but still can't find it, hope everyone will help me. Thanks very much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
      font-size: large;
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    input[type=email] {
      font-size: large;
      width: 400px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
    }

    input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
      display: none;
    }

    label {
      display: block;
      font-size: small;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      color: #999;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="your@email.com">

  <script>
    const EmailDomainSuggester = {
      domains: ["yahoo.com", "gmail.com", "google.com"],
      bindTo: $('#email'),
      init: function () {
        this.addElements();
        this.bindEvents();
      },
      addElements: function () {
        // Create empty datalist
        this.datalist = $("<datalist />", {
          id: 'email-options'
        }).insertAfter(this.bindTo);
        // Corelate to input
        this.bindTo.attr("list", "email-options");
        this.bindTo.attr("autocomplete", "off");
      },
      bindEvents: function () {
        this.bindTo.on("keyup", this.testValue);
      },
      testValue: function (event) {
        let el = $(this),
          value = el.val();
        // email has @
        // remove != -1 to open earlier
        if (value.indexOf("@") != -1) {
          value = value.split("@")[0];
          EmailDomainSuggester.addDatalist(value);
        } else {
          // empty list
          EmailDomainSuggester.datalist.empty();
        }
      },
      addDatalist: function (value) {
        let i, newOptionsString = "";
        for (i = 0; i < this.domains.length; i++) {
          newOptionsString += "<option value='" + value + "@" + this.domains[i] + "'>";
        }
        // add new ones
        this.datalist.html(newOptionsString);
      }
    }
    EmailDomainSuggester.init();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can see that you had only posted the JQuery code. With only this code we are not able to test the issue with the IE and other browsers. I suggest try to provide the proper sample with HTML and JS that we can run in the IE browser to check the issue. Besides that, did you see any error or warning message in the console? Does this code works fine in other browsers?

Comment: sorry, i'll update status.

Comment: I did not receive any error messages.

Comment: For more clarity, you can refer to this video.https://youtu.be/aH9iwkAprD4

Comment: I try to test the issue and it looks like the IE browser works little differently. In my test I noticed that user does not need to click the textbox, if user continue to type the text then IE will show the option. It is just that it will not show options immediately after adding '@'. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/wblC9sE)

Comment: I'm seeing that your IE working is different from my IE. I think is it due to the effect of IE setting or not? Because even if i keep entering characters after character@, autocomplete still won't work.

Comment: I tested your sample on a 2 different machine with IE 11 and on both machine I got the similar result that I had shared with you. On both machines, IE has default settings and no any specific setting was set. I don't think this is due to any setting. I suggest try to clear the cache for that site and again try to test the issue.

Comment: I have seen on my IE work the same as the gif you shared. But I still can't figure out why when I enter @ character, it can't auto-complete in IE browser even in Safari browser.

Comment: I suggest you modify this line `if (value.indexOf("@") != -1)` to `if (value.indexOf("@") >= -1)` in the Jquery code. After that it shows the dropdown while pressing the '@' key. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/8WDg5O3)

Comment: First, I add another little snippet under the if statement, which is to remove the list of data if there is no '@' character in the string. Secondly, I want to thank you for the investigation, but you are using the incorrect condition for this case even though it works on IE. Because when we enter anything other than the '@' character then value.indexOf ("@") = -1 and of course this condition is not satisfied it cannot display the datalist. With your condition, it will display the datalist without entering the '@' character. And this affects other browsers. https://youtu.be/fahVSv6J8PA

Comment: It looks like you are using this [example](https://css-tricks.com/email-domain-datalist-helper/). I again try to check the code and it looks like There is some issue with the IE browser. It is not showing the datalist options after user press the @ key. I suggest you try to provide feedback to Microsoft about this issue and as a workaround for this issue you can try to check the plugin mentioned in the link.

Comment: Because my project originally wanted to use a Datalist, I referenced the above source code as a sample. But I get a lot of comments that Datalist is not supported in Safari. Therefore, I have turned to the other direction of using JqueryUI for this situation. But I still want to continue to investigate why the datalist is not working on IE and Safari, because I have checked and found Datalisst is supported on Safari as in this dashboard https://caniuse.com/datalist. So the reason is that Safari and IE doesn't work.that's what I need to know.

Comment: If you check the [notes](https://imgur.com/a/wE3Zv1X) section in the [link](https://caniuse.com/datalist) you had shared. You can see that the IE browser has a partial support for datalist and there are some known issues. Maybe you are facing the one of the known issue.